# Tailwindcss transition background color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

This is my Home component code

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [currIndex, setCurrIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [startColor, setStartColor] = useState<string>('#3B3B40');
  const [endColor, setEndColor] = useState<string>('#667173');
  const colors = [
    { start: '#3B3B40', end: '#667173' },
    { start: '#735C48', end: '#D9CEC1' },
    { start: '#0B1C26', end: '#590222' },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const startColor = colors[currIndex]?.start;
    const endColor = colors[currIndex]?.end;

    if (startColor && endColor) {
      setStartColor(startColor);
      setEndColor(endColor);
    }
  }, [currIndex]);
  return (
    <div className="font-light">
      <div
        className={`relative w-[360px] h-[360px] pt-14 px-6`}
        style={{
          background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${startColor}, ${endColor})`,
          transition: `background 2s ease-in-out`,
        }}
      >
        <div className="mt-6">
          <Carousel carouselContents={carouselContents} currIndex={currIndex} setCurrIndex={setCurrIndex} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I want to change background color slowly, but it doesn't work.
I guess that change color like this,           background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, ${startColor}, ${endColor})`,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.